# Automating the creation of a weekly schedule

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build an Excel workbook to automate and aid in the creation of a weekly work schedule.

My current workbook is functional, but it's slow - especially on one task where I have a list of people with an annual schedule that I'm searching two sheets at the same time.

I think there's a better and more efficient way than the one I'm using.

```
Option Explicit

'Global variable that will be in another module where i store all general config

Public Const PlanningAgentEmptyRange        As String = "C12:G58,F74:G78" 'Range agent present
Public Const PosteWeekDayRange               As String = "B12:B72" 'Range agent present
Public Const PosteWeekEndRange               As String = "B73:B78" 'Range agent present



Sub DraftFromCycle()

'If range is empty (to prevent the lost of approved schedule)
 If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(PlanningAgentEmptyRange)) = 0 Then


'list of day/col Weekday in weekly schedule
Dim aWeekDay(1 To 5) As String
aWeekDay(1) = "C": aWeekDay(2) = "D": aWeekDay(3) = "E": aWeekDay(4) = "F": aWeekDay(5) = "G"

'List of day/col weekEnd in weekly schedule
Dim aWeekEnd(1 To 2) As String
aWeekEnd(1) = "F": aWeekEnd(2) = "G"

Dim DayDate As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim Col As Variant
Dim DayRangeCycle As Range
Dim DayCycleCol As String
Dim DayCycleRow As Integer
Dim AgentName
Dim p, s, poste, x As variant
Dim Cycle_lastrow As Integer
Dim Cycle_lastcol As String


Cycle_lastrow = LastRow(Feuil55)
Cycle_lastcol = LastCol(Feuil55)


'Loop col/Day  of weekday
For Each Col In aWeekDay

Set DayDate = Range(Col & "11")
Set s = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A5:OA5").Find(What:=DayDate, Lookat:=xlWhole)
           If Not s Is Nothing Then
           DayCycleCol = ColLetter(s.Column)

For Each poste In Worksheets("Cycle").Range(DayCycleCol & "6:" & DayCycleCol & Cycle_lastrow)


Select Case poste
 Case Is = "AM"
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="Après-midi", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
     Do
         If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.Row).Value
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row).Font.Italic = True
         End If
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
     Loop While Not x Is Nothing
    End If

 Case Is = "N"
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="Nuit", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
     Do
         If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.Row).Value
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row).Font.Italic = True
         End If
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
     Loop While Not x Is Nothing
    End If

 Case Is = "R N"
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="Récup Nuit", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
     Do
         If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.Row).Value
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row).Font.Italic = True
         End If
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
     Loop While Not x Is Nothing
    End If

 Case Is = "R Av"
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="R.H. Avant Garde", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
     Do
         If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.Row).Value
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row).Font.Italic = True
         End If
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
     Loop While Not x Is Nothing
    End If

 Case Is = "R Ap"
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="R.H. Après Garde", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
     Do
         If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.Row).Value
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row).Font.Italic = True
         End If
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
     Loop While Not x Is Nothing
    End If

 Case Is = "RTP"
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="R.T.P.", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
     Do
        If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.Row).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row).Font.Italic = True
        End If
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
     Loop While Not x Is Nothing
    End If

 Case Else
End Select

Next poste
End If
Next Col

'Loop col du Week End
For Each Col In aWeekEnd

Set DayDate = Range(Col & "73")
Set s = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A5:OA5").Find(What:=DayDate, Lookat:=xlWhole)
           If Not s Is Nothing Then
           DayCycleCol = ColLetter(s.Column)

For Each poste In Worksheets("Cycle").Range(DayCycleCol & "6:" & DayCycleCol & Cycle_lastrow)


Select Case poste
 Case Is = "AM"
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).Find(What:="Après-midi", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
     Do
         If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.Row).Value
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row).Font.Italic = True
         End If
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).FindNext(x)
     Loop While Not x Is Nothing
    End If

 Case Is = "N"
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).Find(What:="Nuit", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
     Do
         If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.Row).Value
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row).Font.Italic = True
         End If
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).FindNext(x)
     Loop While Not x Is Nothing
    End If

 Case Is = "6h25"
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).Find(What:="6h25 - 13h25", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
     Do
         If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.Row).Value
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row).Font.Italic = True
         End If
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).FindNext(x)
     Loop While Not x Is Nothing
    End If

 Case Is = "7h30"
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).Find(What:="7h30 - 14h30", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
     Do
         If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.Row).Value
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row).Font.Italic = True
         End If
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).FindNext(x)
     Loop While Not x Is Nothing
    End If

 Case Is = "7h45"
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).Find(What:="7h45 - 14h45", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
     Do
         If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = "" Then
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.Row).Value
         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row).Font.Italic = True
         End If
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange).FindNext(x)
     Loop While Not x Is Nothing
    End If

 Case Else
End Select

Next poste
End If
Next Col



End If
End Sub
```

Here's a screen of what the sheets look like. The module takes the data from the annual schedule and autofilled the weekly schedule if it's empty:

**Annual Schedule (Worksheets("Cycle"))**

[image: Annual Schedule (Worksheets("Cycle")]

**Weekly Schedule (Worksheets("1"))**

[image: Weekly Schedule (Worksheets("1")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General Observations

---

**Indentation**

The first thing that I did when I loaded your code up in the VBE was to run an indenter on it.  Without consistent indentation of logical blocks of code (`If` statements, `For Each` bodies, etc.), it is incredibly difficult to get a handle on what the code is doing.  Especially if your `Sub` is 201 lines long.

---

**Case Syntax**

Using `Case Is = "whatever"` is completely redundant. `Case "whatever"` is equivalent, easier to read, and saves a boolean expression evaluation. Also, having an empty `Case Else` is not necessary - it doesn't execute any code, so it simply constitutes noise while reading the `Select` block.

---

**Variable Declarations**

Put these immediately before thier usage. Having to continually scroll up to the top of the `Sub` to see how they are defined is tedious. They'll operate exactly the same way and will be much more readable.

Also, the line `Dim p, s, poste, x As Variant` isn't doing what you think it is doing. Only `x` is explicitly declared as `Variant`. The others are implicitly `Variant`.  But there isn't any *reason* for any of these not to be strongly typed. While it isn't a major performance implication, it does require run-time coercion in most of the places where you use them.

Finally, give your variables meaningful names. If I'm staring at a 201 line procedure and the only information I have (after scrolling all the way to the top) about `p` is that it's a `Variant`, that's not at lot. Don't make me try to determine what everything is simply by context.

---

**Organization**

This definiately needs to be split up into smaller sections.  You are repeating a *ton* of code in blocks like this:

> ```
> Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="Après-midi", Lookat:=xlWhole)
> If Not x Is Nothing Then
>     Do
>         If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = "" Then
>             ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.Row).Value
>             ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row).Font.Italic = True
>         End If
>         Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
>     Loop While Not x Is Nothing
> End If
> ```

Extract the common functionality into another procedure, and then call that. Consider what would happen if you decide to change the formatting - you'd need to make changes in 11 different places. If you extract that out into its own procedure, you have to change it in exactly one place.

---

**Miscellanea**

- The first line of code in `DraftFromCycle` is basically a guard clause.  If it evaluates to `False`, nothing executes. I'd invert the condition to make it clear that's what it is:

  ```
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(PlanningAgentEmptyRange)) <> 0 Then
      Exit Sub
  End If
  ```
- Use the built in VBA constant `vbNullString` instead of the literal `""`.  It's easier to read, easier to search for, and doesn't require a memory allocation.
- I consider `Dim Cycle_lastrow As Integer` to be an error. If you're using a variable to store a row number, then it should be a `Long`. You can overflow an `Integer` with a call to `.Row`. These are basically treated as `Long` internally, so there's generally not much reason to use `Integer` unless you're building a `Type` that needs to be memory aligned.
- Don't use column letters. Excel treats them as numbers internally, so what happens is that you convert (or ask Excel to convert) them to a letter. Then you build a range out of the letter in A1 format (string concatenation isn't free either), then pass it to Excel, which has to ***convert it back into a number***. This is simply wasted CPU cycles.
- You aren't changing the `ActiveSheet` anywhere in this code. If this is intended to run on a the active worksheet, grab a reference at the start and use that. You shouldn't risk the wheels coming off it it somehow changes while your code is running.

---

### Performance

Repeatedly calculating things that are guaranteed to have the same result is simply wasted CPU time.  For example, in this block of code...

> ```
> Do
>     If ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = "" Then
>         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row) = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A" & poste.Row).Value
>         ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row).Font.Italic = True
>     End If
>     Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
> Loop While Not x Is Nothing
> ```

... `ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row)` is going to be exactly the same each of the ***3 times*** you call it. Either cache the result in a variable and use that or wrap it in a `With` block:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row)
    If .Value = vbNullString Then
        .Value = Worksheets("Cycle").Cells(poste.Row, 1).Value
        .Font.Italic = True
    End If
    Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
End With
```

---

The `Range.Find` and `Range.FindNext` functions are ridiculously slow given the tiny ranges that you're searching in. On top of that, they *never change*. Using a cached lookup will destroy this in performance. You would build the lookup with a function something like this...

```
'Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
'Build a lookup keyed by a string identifier, with values containing a Collection of cells
Private Function GetLookupForRange(source As Range) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim lookup As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set lookup = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim currentCell As Range
    For Each currentCell In source
        Dim identifier As String
        identifier = currentCell.Value
        Dim results As Collection
        If Not lookup.Exists(identifier) Then
            Set results = New Collection
            lookup.Add identifier, results
        Else
            Set results = lookup.Item(identifier)
        End If
        results.Add currentCell
    Next

    Set GetLookupForRange = lookup
End Function
```

...and initialize it at the start of the procedure...

```
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet

Dim weekdayLookup As Scripting.Dictionary
Set weekdayLookup = GetLookupForRange(targetSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange))
```

...then use that to replace your `.Find` with a simple iteration of the cached results for that identifier. This code...

> ```
> Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).Find(What:="Après-midi", Lookat:=xlWhole)
> If Not x Is Nothing Then
>     Do
>         With ActiveSheet.Range(Col & x.Row)
>             If .Value = vbNullString Then
>                 .Value = Worksheets("Cycle").Cells(poste.Row, 1).Value
>                 .Font.Italic = True
>             End If
>             Set x = ActiveSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange).FindNext(x)
>         End With
>     Loop While Not x Is Nothing
> End If
> ```

...becomes this:

```
'I should be extracted as a function!
If weekdayLookup.Exists("Après-midi") Then
    'The first "found" item is the first Collection member.
    Dim results As Collection
    Set results = weekdayLookup.Item("Après-midi")
    Dim currentResult As Range
    'You can now simply loop through the cached results.
    For Each currentResult In results
        Dim targetCell As Range
        'Col should be a number, remember?
        Set targetCell = targetSheet.Cells(currentResult.Row, Col)
        With targetCell
            If .Value = vbNullString Then
                .Value = Worksheets("Cycle").Cells(poste.Row, 1).Value
                .Font.Italic = True
            End If
        End With
    Next
End If
```

---

Given the number of cells that you're accessing, the next thing I would do would be to collect all of the formatting changes into a single union of ranges - then set all of the formatting in one operation.  This prevents one of the two redraws every time you set a cell to italic.

```
'At the top.
Dim italicized As Range
```

Then when you identify a cell that needs to be formatted, you can do this...

```
If .Value = vbNullString Then
    .Value = Worksheets("Cycle").Cells(poste.Row, 1).Value
    If italicized Is Nothing Then
        Set italicized = targetCell
    Else
        Application.Union italicized, targetCell
    End If
End If
```

...and format the whole mess in one shot:

```
'At the very bottom.
italicized.Font.Italic = True
```

---

Finally, now that you've converted your A1 addressing to Row\Column, it becomes fairly trivial to switch to array processing as opposed to setting values of individual cells.  Give the current length of the answer, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader (or another reviewer).  Even *without* array processing, the suggestions noted above should be a huge performance win - that would just be icing on the cake...

Answer (score 0):

**Indentation**

I tried to do it manually, i didn't know that it could have been automated. I've downloaded an Add-on and yes it's much better

---

**Case Syntax**

The change have been made

---

**Variable Declarations**

I've changed the name of the variable to be more meaningful. The declaration are fixed.

---

**Organization**

The code is much more readable with the block in another Sub.

---

**Miscellaneous**

Proposed changes have been made, the code is looking more and cleaner.

---

**Performance**

I've cached the range in a variable and replaced col letter by col number.

With all of these modification when I added `EnableEvent = False` it worked (it didn't before) and well it's instantaneous.

Small hiccups with the lookup function (that I'm not quite understanding) the code take the name of the same person and put it multiple time in the Weekly schedule.

**EDIT: I added as small variable to prevent duplicate and it is working fine**

And I didn't quite yet manage the italicized but I looking to get it up and running.

---

**Updated code**

```
 Option Explicit

Public Const PlanningAgentEmptyRange         As String = "C12:G58,F74:G78" 'Range agent present
Public Const PosteWeekDayRange               As String = "B12:B72" 'Range agent present
Public Const PosteWeekEndRange               As String = "B73:B78" 'Range agent present

Dim cel As Variant
Dim Col As Variant 'Column

Sub DraftFromCycle()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(PlanningAgentEmptyRange)) <> 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Loop through the 5 day of the week
    For Col = 3 To 7

        Dim DayDateActiveSheet As Range ' Date 01/01/2001 of the Column
        Set DayDateActiveSheet = ActiveSheet.Cells(11, Col)

        Dim FindDayDateCycle As Variant
        Set FindDayDateCycle = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A5:OA5").Find(What:=DayDateActiveSheet, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not FindDayDateCycle Is Nothing Then

            With Worksheets("Cycle")
                Dim DayRangeCycle As Range
                Set DayRangeCycle = .Range(.Cells(6, FindDayDateCycle.Column), .Cells(LastRow(Feuil55), FindDayDateCycle.Column))
            End With

            For Each cel In DayRangeCycle
                Select Case cel
                    Case "AM"
                        Call RepeatWeekDay("Après-midi")

                    Case "N"
                        Call RepeatWeekDay("Nuit")

                    Case "R N"
                        Call RepeatWeekDay("Récup Nuit")

                    Case "R Av"
                        Call RepeatWeekDay("R.H. Avant Garde")

                    Case "R Ap"
                        Call RepeatWeekDay("R.H. Après Garde")

                    Case "RTP"
                        Call RepeatWeekDay("R.T.P.")

                    Case "TC"
                        Call RepeatWeekDay("T.C.")

                    Case "BM"
                        Call RepeatWeekDay("Biomol")

                    Case "CMF"
                        Call RepeatWeekDay("C.M.F.")

                    Case Is = "URC"
                        Call RepeatWeekDay("U.R.C.")

                End Select

            Next cel
        End If

    Next Col

    'Loop col du Week End
    For Col = 6 To 7

        Set DayDateActiveSheet = ActiveSheet.Cells(73, Col)
        Set FindDayDateCycle = Worksheets("Cycle").Range("A5:OA5").Find(What:=DayDateActiveSheet, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not FindDayDateCycle Is Nothing Then

            With Worksheets("Cycle")
                Set DayRangeCycle = .Range(.Cells(6, FindDayDateCycle.Column), .Cells(LastRow(Feuil55), FindDayDateCycle.Column))
            End With

            For Each cel In DayRangeCycle

                Select Case cel
                    Case "AM"
                        Call RepeatWeekEnd("Après-midi")

                    Case "N"
                        Call RepeatWeekEnd("Nuit")

                    Case "6h25"
                        Call RepeatWeekEnd("6h25 - 13h25")

                    Case Is = "7h30"
                        Call RepeatWeekEnd("7h30 - 14h30")

                    Case "7h45"
                        Call RepeatWeekEnd("7h45 - 14h45")


                End Select

            Next cel
        End If
    Next Col

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With


End Sub

Sub RepeatWeekDay(FindPoste As String)
    'Public Const PosteWeekDayRange               As String = "B12:B72" 'Range agent present
    'Public Const PosteWeekEndRange               As String = "B73:B78" 'Range agent present

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet

    Dim weekdayLookup As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set weekdayLookup = GetLookupForRange(targetSheet.Range(PosteWeekDayRange))

    If weekdayLookup.Exists(FindPoste) Then
        'The first "found" item is the first Collection member.
        Dim results As Collection
        Set results = weekdayLookup.Item(FindPoste)
        Dim currentResult As Range
        'You can now simply loop through the cached results.
        For Each currentResult In results
            Dim targetCell As Range
            'Col should be a number, remember?
            Set targetCell = targetSheet.Cells(currentResult.Row, Col)
            With targetCell
                Dim previousrow As Long
                If previousrow <> cel.Row Then
                If .Value = vbNullString Then
                    .Value = Worksheets("Cycle").Cells(cel.Row, 1).Value
                    .Font.Italic = True
                    previousrow = cel.Row
                End If
                End If

            End With
        Next
    End If

End Sub

Sub RepeatWeekEnd(FindPoste As String)
      Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet

    Dim weekdayLookup As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set weekdayLookup = GetLookupForRange(targetSheet.Range(PosteWeekEndRange))

    If weekdayLookup.Exists(FindPoste) Then
        'The first "found" item is the first Collection member.
        Dim results As Collection
        Set results = weekdayLookup.Item(FindPoste)
        Dim currentResult As Range
        'You can now simply loop through the cached results.
        For Each currentResult In results
            Dim targetCell As Range
            'Col should be a number, remember?
            Set targetCell = targetSheet.Cells(currentResult.Row, Col)
            With targetCell
                Dim previousrow As Long
                If previousrow <> cel.Row Then
                If .Value = vbNullString Then
                    .Value = Worksheets("Cycle").Cells(cel.Row, 1).Value
                    .Font.Italic = True
                    previousrow = cel.Row
                End If
                End If

            End With
        Next
    End If
    End Sub

'Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
'Build a lookup keyed by a string identifier, with values containing a Collection of cells
Private Function GetLookupForRange(source As Range) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim lookup As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set lookup = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim currentCell As Range
    For Each currentCell In source
        Dim identifier As String
        identifier = currentCell.Value
        Dim results As Collection
        If Not lookup.Exists(identifier) Then
            Set results = New Collection
            lookup.Add identifier, results
        Else
            Set results = lookup.Item(identifier)
        End If
        results.Add currentCell
    Next

    Set GetLookupForRange = lookup
End Function
```

Comment: Re your question "can I Dim variable inside a For Each loop", the answer is yes. The declaration can go anywhere. For the numeric `Range` indexing, you would use `.Cells(row, column)` for an individual cell.  If you need more than one it would be `.Range(.Cells(startRow, startColumn), .Cells(endRow, endColumn))`

Comment: @Comintern while you _can_ put the `Dim` inside the loop, it's pointless and misleading.  It only executes once, the first time it's encountered.

Comment: @Comintern [here's a post dealing with that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970613/445425)

Comment: @chrisneilsen It's not "pointless" or "misleading", it simply moves the declaration to a place in the code where it is next to the assignment or usage. The only rule that VBA enforces is that it has to be declared *before its first use*.  The assumption that it *would* reset on each iteration of the loop is an odd one, in that scope is determined by procedure in VBA, not on enclosures.

Comment: @Comintern putting something inside a loop that's not executed on each iteration of the loop is, in my view, misleading.  Especially when similar constructs in many other languages _do_ reinitialize on each iteration. But, to each his own.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Then don't do it. The main point I was trying to address is that you don't need to put everything in a `Dim` wall at the top of a multi-hundred line procedure. I personally don't have an opinion on whether or not they should be inside the loop or outside, but on a purely technical level it really doesn't matter. I *do* take a declaration inside the loop as a visual cue that the variable should only be *used* inside the loop though - it's probably just a different interpretation of "similar constructs many in other languages".